# Function called by settimeout not ending

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Problem: In a slide show the fade function below keeps calling the fadein/out functions, please JsFiddle and run for about ten seconds to see problem. Does not work in IE, don't let the jsfiddle run too long it'll probably crash your browser!

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HdYmH/

Details (for those interested) : Hi, sorry for posting a question with such a large code chunk. I'm still learning javascript and was trying to figure out how to make a slideshow. I know there are a lot of js slideshows out there but I wanted to figure it out as a learning experience. So be warned there are parts of this code that are very bad. The problem is probably related to the slideshow's changeSlide() method.

I used firebug to find out which method was being called the most apparently after a few seconds fadeOut will be called 20k+ times :|

```
// Generic fade function that fades in or out
function fade(pElem, pStartOpac, pEndOpac, fps, sec) {
    if ((typeof (pElem) !== "string") || (typeof (pStartOpac) !== "number")
            || (typeof (pEndOpac) !== "number") || (typeof (fps) !== "number")
            || (typeof (sec) !== "number")) {
        console.log("Parameters incorrect format has to be (string) Element Id, (double) Starting Opacity, (double) End Opacity, (integer) frames per second, (integer) seconds to run");
        return;
    }
    // The CSS opacity property only works from 1 to 0
    if (pStartOpac < 0) {
        pStartOpace = 0;
    }
    if (pStartOpac > 1) {
        pStartOpac = 1;
    }
    if (pEndOpac < 0) {
        pEndOpac = 0;
    }
    if (pEndOpac > 1) {
        pEndOpac = 1;
    }

    // Stop the fps from going over 60 or under 1 (The eye will barely notice
    // improvements above 60fps and fractional fps are not supported)
    if (fps > 60) {
        fps = 60;
    }
    if (fps < 1) {
        fps = 1;
    }

    var totalFrames = (fps * sec);
    var opacityChangePerSecond = (Math.abs(pStartOpac - pEndOpac) / sec);
    var opacityChangePerFrame = (opacityChangePerSecond / fps);
    var timeOutInterval = 1000 * (1 / fps);

    // console.log("totalFrames: "+totalFrames);
    // console.log("Opacity change per second: " + opacityChangePerSecond);
    // console.log("Opacity change per frame: " + opacityChangePerFrame);
    // console.log("Time out interval: " + timeOutInterval + " milliseconds");

    var opacity = pStartOpac;
    var timeoutVar;
    var elemId = document.getElementById(pElem);
    elemId.style.opacity = opacity;

    if (pStartOpac < pEndOpac) {
        fadeIn();
        return;
    } else {
        fadeOut();
        return;
    }

    function fadeIn() {
        opacity = opacity + opacityChangePerFrame;
        if (opacity > pEndOpac) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
            return;
        }
        elemId.style.opacity = opacity;
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(fadeIn, timeOutInterval);
        return;
    }

    function fadeOut() {
        if (opacity < pEndOpac) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
            return;
        }
        opacity = opacity - opacityChangePerFrame;
        if (opacity < 0) {
            opacity = 0;
        }
        elemId.style.opacity = opacity;
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(fadeOut, timeOutInterval);
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem: when opacity gets <0 you set it to 0, and then do: `if (opacity < pEndOpac)`. pEndOpac is 0 so, 0<0 evaluates to false and timeout is never cleared. The solution is to do `if (opacity <= pEndOpac)`:

```
function fadeIn() {
    opacity = opacity + opacityChangePerFrame;
    if (opacity >= pEndOpac) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
        return;
    }
    elemId.style.opacity = opacity;
    timeoutVar = setTimeout(fadeIn, timeOutInterval);
    return;
}

function fadeOut() {
    if (opacity <= pEndOpac) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
        return;
    }
    opacity = opacity - opacityChangePerFrame;
    if (opacity < 0) {
        opacity = 0;
    }
    elemId.style.opacity = opacity;
    timeoutVar = setTimeout(fadeOut, timeOutInterval);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the change you suggested, unfortunately it didn't work. I also don't see how that is different from what I have right now, the timeoutVar is only cleared when the element reaches the end opacity. With the way I'm using it is only cleared when the opacity is at 0.

Comment: @user1490379 You're right, I was missing something. I've edited my answer to show a problem you have.

Comment: Wow nice eye, I feel dumb lol thanks a lot for the quick debug and response!